# Find all row and execute code for each row in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have function like this in asp.net :

```
DataTable dt = dal.ExecuteDataTable(CommandType.Text, "SELECT KID FROM Chart", new SqlParameter[] { });

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Update(Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows[i]["KID"]));
}
```

What is the equivalent of this code in SQl? Can we execute both of select and update in one procedure ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?  What is the problem that you are attempting to solve?

Comment: I want execute both of select and update in SQL Instead asp.net

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Yes it is possible in SQL.

```
1. Create temporary table in SQL.
2. Insert data into temporary table.
3. Access temp table data using while loop.
4. update single record one by one in while loop.
```

> Select and update in single statment : [How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)
>
> Using temp table : [In SQL Server, how to create while loop in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891594/in-sql-server-how-to-create-while-loop-in-select)